# multi language Website configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, multilingual

i have list box that contain a group of different language :

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" uiculture="auto" %>
  <%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
  <%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
 <script runat="server">
 protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
if (Request.Form["ListBox1"] != null)
{
    String selectedLanguage = Request.Form["ListBox1"];
    UICulture = selectedLanguage ;
    Culture = selectedLanguage ;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
        CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
        CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
}
base.InitializeCulture();
}
</script>
<html>
 <head><title>Set Culture</title></head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="en-US" Selected="True">English</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="es-MX">Español</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="de-DE">Deutsch</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Set Language"  />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="my name is"  />

  </div>
</form>
 </body>
  </html>
```

I want when i choose a language from my listbox the label text will be translated for the chosen language for example if i choose Español "my name is " will be translated to Español language and displayed to the screen

Comment: do you want to change the label name only or do you want to change the CultureInfo so that all the content (resources) in the website should change to the selected language?

Comment: i want all the content of the website to change to the selected language yes  not only the label text value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove the hard coded string and start using `Resource` files. I recommend you take a look at [this](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=3477182) tutorial for a complete guide on how to develop a multi-lingual website.

Comment: @BassemAssemAlameddine: This: `Text="my name is"`.

Comment: that's just an example i put so i can explain my issue

Comment: @BassemAssemAlameddine: Very well I understand. But just as an FYI, to have multi-lingual applications you ditch all hard coded strings and use resource files.

Answer (score 1):

Write the following line of code in selectedIndexChanged event of ListBox

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(selectedLanguageCode);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguageCode);
```

selectedLanguageCode is something specify for each culture e.g. for US english en-US etc..

Comment: The code which you have written is in initialize culture event , write given line in selected index change event of listbox so that everytime you change the event it should set the culture again.

Comment: just saw one of my project implementation and found additional line needs to be specify, edited my answer now there are two lines of code you have to write

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this

```
 protected override void InitializeCulture()
```

on every page you need multi languages.
I usually make a class where override it and derive other multi language supported pages from that one. you will also need to use coockies. coockies["lang"] = "en-US" -  something like this to manage languages.

Comment: that's not what i want to achieve i want to create a multi language website not only change the value of my label on select change

Comment: @BassemAssemAlameddine: I posted a link to such tutorial which should get you on the right track. I recommend you take a look at it.